# custom background image for every WordPress page?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i am trying to have different header background images depending on which inner page is accessed. Right now i have the same picture for all inner pages and need the php code changed so its conditional. Like if im on contact page, 1.jpg to be set as header img. If on services page, 2.jpg to be set as header img etc, you get the idea.
Here is the php code ive found in this wp theme im trying to improve for a friend:

```
        <div class="bgtop">
      <?php 
        //display featured image if one exists
        $featimage = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . "/images/pageheader.png";

        if ((has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ))&&(!is_single()&&(!is_category())) ){

          $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
          $featimage = $image[0];
             } 

      ?>


      <div class="pageheader" style="background: url(<?php echo $featimage; ?> ); background-position: center top;">
          <div class="centermenu">
         <div class="pagelogo">
              <!--<a href="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>">
                  <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/indexlogo.png" alt="logo" />
                </a>-->
    </div>
```

Comment: i am bad at php and tried for hours to find the way to add that header bg pic depending on the page visited. cant figure out im stuck..

Comment: Depending on the amount of images/pages, you might be better off using CSS.

Comment: add a different class or id to the body tag depending on the page and do this with css

Comment: @relentless  just 5 pages, no biggie.

Comment: @Rooster  how do i do that? there are no unique body ids attached to the pages so i can use that..

Comment: check the wordpress codex for the function that gives you the page name, and then use that function in your header to add the name to the <body> tag.  THen you can write a different css rule for the same div as many ways as there are pages

Comment: I don't think you're familiar with how to structure a website using php pages. It seems like you're trying to serve the entire site from one script. See optional solution below if you want to continue the way you are. But I'd advise against it.

Comment: @Paul_R  yes, this is all strange to me and using one script for all pages was a bad idea from original coder. I am trying to give unique ids to pages, as rooster suggested, and use css...

Comment: Just change it to a clean structure. It's always a bad idea to continue to develop on messy code. Take the little bit of time to clean it up and it will save you bundles down the road. css classes don't seem like a good idea either. See solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. It's more of a structure thing. How are you determining which page they are on? Does the user click a link? Use the information available to the server to decide what content to serve. If you're using one script to serve all your pages, then you'll need to pass it a parameter when the user clicks a link. You can do this by making your links take parameters.

Markup like so:

```
<a href='default.php?page=home'> Navigate To Home </a>
<a href='default.php?page=blog'> Navigate To Blog </a>
```

php like so:

```php
if($_POST['page'] == "home")
    echo $homeheader;
elseif($_POST['page'] == "blog")
    echo $blogheader;
```

But, usually you just make multiple php pages that include some common elements (called templating). That helps keep things cleaner than making one php script that serves up your whole site.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the manage this in the back-end of WordPress: You can use the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin for WordPress (http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). Through it, you can add a field on every page an even every post that allows you to enter in a background image.

Then, in your header.php template file, add the shortcode somewhere in your body tag:

`<body background="(<?php the_field('background_image')" ?>)">`

Depending on what page you're on, it will show that background image.

---

If You'd like the process automated: You can create a folder called "bg" and have an image with the same name as your page. For example, for about.php you can have about.jpg.

Then write a script that takes the page name, and then sets the background image to that name. You would place this in the `header.php` file in your template Something like:

```
 $page = end(explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
 $image = str_replace("php","jpg",$page);
```

Then use:
`<body background="bg/<?php print $image ?>">`

This is assuming that you are keeping your image files in `http://www.yoursite.com/bg/` But you can also use shortcodes to keep these images within your theme with `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>`